# Accessing fields in Visualforce from a complex Apex Structure

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've got a structure like this in apex `public Map <string, List <custom__c>> extIdTOSFRecords{get; set;}`

In a column in visualforce I can feed the map the key. I want to:

1. iterate over the custom objects
2. access some fields in each list element

I tried this syntax, but it's not working

`<apex:variable value="{!item.customfield__c}" var="mapKey"/>`

`extIdTOSFRecords[mapKey]-->{!extIdTOSFRecords[mapKey]}<br/>`

Results

`extIdTOSFRecords[mapKey]--> extIdTOSFRecords[mapKey]-->[]`

how do I work with this data structure?

Comment: You need to bind the `Map` items with `pageblocktable` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over a `Map` and bind with `apex:pageBlockTable`s as below.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!extIdTOSFRecords}" var="key">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!extIdTOSFRecords[key]}" var="listItem">
            <apex:column value="{!listItem.YOUR_CUS_OBJ_FIELD}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:repeat>
```